# Sci-Fi anime about a fever, vaccine and transgender pilot

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm looking for the title of an anime, possibly from 1990.

It's about a group of pilots from various planets on their final test. The first complication is that there is one extra pilot among them. Second, the ship they boarded is losing trajectory, and because of this it is overheating, causing vines used as electricity cable to grow and emit toxic spores. The only known vaccine is made from mice that lived on the ship. One of the pilots is a survivor of the original outbreak that caused the ship to be abandoned in the first place. Another one of the pilots is transgender. They team up to save the ship.

That's all I remember. Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, much of the description feels like a riff off of "The Cold Equations", right up until the happy ending.

Answer (score 7):

This anime is *They Were Eleven*. It was produced in 1986, and first released in the United States in the early 1990s. Everything matches your description - the ten cadets with one additional mystery member, the decaying orbit falling into a star, and the overgrown vine cables.

Here is the spaceship:

[image]
[image]

Here are the eleven cadets:

[image]

Here are the conductor vines overgrowing everything:

[image]
[image]

And the heat warning as the ship approaches the star:

[image]

All of these screencaps and more are found at [Gary's They Were Eleven Page](http://inetres.com/gp/anime/tw11/index.html)